# Weird printf behaviour with inet_ntoa

Tags: c, sockets, printf

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    struct sockaddr_in X = {0};
    X.sin_family = AF_INET;
    X.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    X.sin_port = htons(8080);

    struct sockaddr_in Y = {0};
    Y.sin_family = AF_INET;
    Y.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("212.43.159.20");
    Y.sin_port = htons(80);

    printf("X:Y %s:%s\n", inet_ntoa(X.sin_addr), inet_ntoa(Y.sin_addr));
    printf("X %s\n", inet_ntoa(X.sin_addr));
    printf("Y %s\n", inet_ntoa(Y.sin_addr));

    return 0;
}
```

Why does first pritnf print same IP twice rather than whats given?
Second and third seem to be okay.
Seems to happend on linux gcc/clang and freebsd clang, is this is something known?

Answer (score 5):

From the man page for `inet_ntoa`:

> The `inet_ntoa()` function converts the Internet host address in given
>   in network  byte  order to a string in standard numbers-and-dots
>   notation. **The string is returned in a statically allocated buffer, 
>   which subsequent calls will overwrite.**

Since `inet_ntoa` uses a static buffer for its output, and because you call it twice in one function call, `printf` gets passed two copies of the same pointer.  It contains the contents of whichever call was done last.

You need to split the printing into two separate calls, like you do in the following lines.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the POSIX docs for [`inet_ntoa`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/inet_ntoa.html), notable the "Application Usage" section:

> The return value of `inet_ntoa()` **may point to static data that may be overwritten by subsequent calls** to `inet_ntoa()`.

This is what is happening here: one of the two calls in your first `printf` is overwriting what the other did (and you don't know which one - order of evaluation of function arguments is implementation defined).

So either stick with two printfs, or copy the string returned by `inet_ntoa` into your own buffers and then print them.

Comment: I tend to avoid this issue by using `inet_ntop` instead.